# Variable in upper pipeline not accessible

Tags: powershell

Variable $Comp is not accessible in pipeline export-csv. The output excel file name becomes like ''_Users.csv

```
get-content "Servers.txt" | foreach-object {
   $Comp = $_
   if (test-connection -computername $Comp -count 1 -quiet)
   {
   } Else 
   {
       Write-Warning "Server '$Comp' is Unreachable hence Could not fetch data"
   }
}|Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation "'$Comp'_Users.csv"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the exception of script-block arguments, **command-line arguments are bound *once, before pipeline processing starts***.

Therefore, `$Comp` in your `"'$Comp'_Users.csv"` argument (I assume you meant `"$Comp_Users.csv"`) is expanded *before* the script block passed to `ForEach-Object` is ever called.

- At that point it either evaluates to `$null`, if `$Comp` was never initialized - which becomes the *empty string* in an expandable string, as your symptom shows - or it uses any preexisting `$Comp` value.

In order to export to a different file for each input object (line in file `Servers.txt`), you'll have to **move the `Export-Csv` call into the `ForEach-Object` script block**.